# Spring boot 2 micormeter to statsd prefix not appending to the metrics

Tags: graphite, statsd, spring-micrometer, spring-boot-2

I've migrated spring boot 1.x to spring boot 2 with micrometer for metrics. After which could see the metrics in graphite via statsd. But, i can't see it with the prefix

After that i tried for basic prototype by following [Configure micrometer-registry-statsd in spring boot 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56735269/configure-micrometer-registry-statsd-in-spring-boot-2). But, can't see metrics with prefix. It is showing from the registry name only

config:

`management:
  health:
    defaults:
      enabled: true
  metrics:
    enable:
      example:
        remote: true
    export:
      atlas:
        enabled: false
      statsd:
        enabled: true
        host: xx.xxx.xx.xx
        port: xxxx
        flavour: xxxx
        step: 10s
        **prefix: abc.xy**
  security:
    enabled: false`

when i tried to print the statsdConfig properties the prefix shows as default value "statsd". After which i set the prefix property in the code too. That too didn't help.

Please share details on how to append the statsd.prefix