Spring boot micrometer ignores management.metrics.export.statsd.host setting
I am trying to add StatsD metrics to a Spring boot application using Micrometer.
It works locally, but fails in production, logging errors saying that its unable to connect to localhost:8125 despite having management.metrics.export.statsd.host configured correctly.
I added an endpoint to the service that returns the value of the management.metrics.export.statsd.host application property, and it returns the value I configured, so this part seems to be good, but for some reason the management.metrics.export.statsd.host application property is ignored by micrometer.
I added StatsD metrics reporting to my app by adding this to the pom.xml file:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-statsd</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version>
        </dependency>

And adding this to the application.properties file:
management.metrics.export.statsd.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.statsd.host=deliberately_broken
management.metrics.export.statsd.port=8125

On my local machine it successfully outputs metrics to localhost in spite of having deliberately_broken as the configured host name, and on production it also tries to send metrics to localhost even though this application property is set correctly.

According to the official docs, the property you should use for Spring Boot 3.x is management.statsd.metrics.export.host.
The property was management.metrics.export.statsd.host previously in Spring Boot 2.x which is no longer supported.
Since it is a Boot property, it should be found in the official Boot docs, see: management.statsd.metrics.export.host

All the places I found specify management.metrics.export.statsd.* for example https://docs.micrometer.io/micrometer/reference/implementations/statsD.html#_configuring and many many others. There are also many SO articles where other people have picked up on these config settings, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56735269/configure-micrometer-registry-statsd-in-spring-boot-2

Maybe there is a place where this is documented correctly, but there are hundreds of places where it is incorrect, so finding the right config is like finding a needle in a haystack.

The name of the property was changed In Boot 3.x so it is different for Boot 2.x and for 3.x. This made references for the old properties out of date for Boot 3.x. The single source of truth is the official Spring Boot docs for the same version you use.

I updated your answer with this info.

After many frustrating hours of searching the web and trying various experiments, I finally found a way to make it work. It's pretty sad that none of the Spring or Micrometer or StatsD documentation actually tells you how to make it work even for the most basic use case. It's also pretty sad that it's necessary to write a load of code just to get Spring/Micrometer/StatsD to behave as per the documentation.
The solution I found may not be the perfect answer, but it did work for me. This is the class that I added to my application:
@Configuration
public class MicrometerConfig {
  @Value("${management.metrics.export.statsd.host}")
  private String host;

  @Value("${management.metrics.export.statsd.port}")
  private Integer port;

  @Value("${management.metrics.export.statsd.enabled}")
  private boolean enabled;

  @Bean
  @Scope("singleton")
  public StatsdConfig buildStatsdConfig() {
    return new StatsdConfig() {
      @Override
      public String get(String s) {
        return s;
      }

      @Override
      public String prefix() {
        return "";
      }

      @Override
      public boolean enabled() {
        return enabled;
      }

      @Override
      public String host() {
        return host == null ? "localhost" : host;
      }

      @Override
      public int port() {
        return port == null ? 8125 : port;
      }

      @Override
      public StatsdFlavor flavor() {
        return StatsdFlavor.DATADOG;
      }

      @Override
      public StatsdProtocol protocol() {
        return StatsdProtocol.UDP;
      }

      @Override
      public Duration pollingFrequency() {
        return Duration.ofSeconds(5);
      }

      @Override
      public Duration step() {
        return Duration.ofMinutes(1);
      }
    };
  }

  @Bean
  @Scope("singleton")
  public StatsdMeterRegistry buildStatsdMeterRegistry(StatsdConfig statsdConfig) {
    StatsdMeterRegistry registry =
        StatsdMeterRegistry.builder(statsdConfig).clock(Clock.SYSTEM).build();
    return registry;
  }
}


With this in place, modifying the application.properties according to the Spring/Micrometer/StatsD documentation does now work as expected.
